# Why is my IP resolved to 127.0.0.1 instead of the IP I have in the network?

Tags: networking

I have a problem understanding how IP resolving works on Linux systems. To demonstrate my problem I'll show an example on Windows and afterwards on Linux.

**Windows:**
The Windows `hosts` file is empty. It only contains comments.

Running the following command in a Python shell:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

I get `192.168.10.105` which is my current IP in the network I am in. As I expected it to be.

**Linux**: 
On Linux my `/etc/hosts` looks as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain           localhost
```

The same Python command would give me errors that the resource is temporarily unavailable. I am guessing that it has to do with the absence of the my current Hostname from `/etc/hosts`. If I add it manually

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain           localhost    MyHostName
```

the python command returns `127.0.0.1`. Which is still not what I expected it to be. I can however add the IP and my hostname to the file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain           localhost
192.168.10.115  MyHostName
```

but this is surely not the correct way to go. If DHCP is used this IP would change.

How can I achieve the same result on Linux as on Windows? Where is my configuration (or my thinking?) wrong?

Comment: which dhcp client do you use in linux? **ps -ef|grep dhcp**

Comment: @LilloX `udhcpc`. But this also has happended to me with all smaller devices I use. For example Raspberry Pi 2 (I don't knwo right now which dhcp client it uses by default).

Comment: what is wrong with using `127.0.0.1  MyHostName`?

Comment: @user4668401 On this device is a webserver running where I also use websockets. They require to know the IP the device has in the network for communication.

Comment: ok I see, what about an `ifconfig`  query? executed through shell? e.g. `ipaddress=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep --color=always inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed -n '1p' | sed 's/\/[[:digit:]]*//g')
`

Comment: I will try your and the answer from LilloX later. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how python handles sockets, but if you have a socket (that is a pair of ip, port), you should be able to get extract the ip part without having to pass by the host (which is needed for instance when there are several interfaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the file that contains the instructions to execute when assigned the IP to your network card (/etc/udhcpc/default.script).

A change that you can do is the following: 
in the **renew|bound** section add, under the ifconfig instruction :

```
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost"> /etc/hosts
echo "$i myHostName" > /etc/hosts
```

Comment: better yet, don't erase and re-create the entire hosts file, use sed to change only the line with myHostName: `sed -i -e "/myHostName/ s/^\([0-9.]\+\)/$i/" /etc/hosts`.   or edit it if it exists, add it otherwise: `if grep -q myHostName /etc/hosts ; then sed -i -e "/myHostName/ s/^\([0-9.]\+\)/$i/" /etc/hosts ; else echo "$i myHostName" >> /etc/hosts ; fi`

Comment: Thank you. This will work. But I am also interested in what the difference in Windows handling there is. Is there a configuration issue that Linux cannot resolve my Hostname to my network IP when DHCP is used or is this only achieveable with static IPs and enterening those into `/etc/hosts`?